# Linux and windows instance on AWS

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services

How can I create a VPC/subnet on AWS and launch a Windows instance and Linux instance in that same subnet. whenever I try to create a vpc it will not give ssh access to other terminals even though I give permissions in route tables.

Comment: So you have actually created the Windows and Linux instances, but your problem is that you can't SSH from the Windows instance to the Linux instance? But you can remote desktop to the Windows instance and SSH into the Linux instance? Are you trying to connect to the internal IPs in the subnet, or the public IPs?

Answer (score 0):

This could be many things. I'd probably recommend looking at security groups (adding TCP/22 inbound from your IP address) and depending on your setup (make sure an IGW is attached), making sure a public IP address is assigned to your instances (add an Elastic IP if your instance doesn't already have one). Without more information on your environment, I can only provide some background to help you troubleshoot.

The network path to an instance in a VPC looks like this:

Internet -> AWS Boundary -> VPC Boundary -> VPC Router -> Subnet boundary -> Elastic Network Interface

## AWS Boundary

Most of the time this part isn't important. From the Internet, eventually your traffic will be routed into an Amazon autonomous system. This is generally transparent. But if you have a public-type Direct Connect, the Amazon side of the connection dumps you here. In this area, you can access public API endpoints, but you cannot access anything within a VPC without progressing further down the stack. See below.

## VPC Boundary

This is the point at which traffic enters/leaves the VPC. There are a number of ways this can occur.

#### Internet Gateway (IGW)

This performs a one-to-one NAT between an amazon-owned publicly routable IP address and a VPC internal private IP address (do not confuse this with a NAT Gateway, as that's different and described below). Only instances assigned a public IP address can use an IGW. Being a 1-to-1 NAT, to the Instances perspective it's a connection between it's private IP address and an Internet-routable IP. From the outside it's a connection to the instance's public IP address. To stress, instances without a public IP address assigned (elastic IP or otherwise) will *not* be able to communicate with the Internet in either direction through an IGW. Conversely, if you don't have an IGW, there is no use for public IP addresses on your instances. Also worth mentioning, there are also egress-only gateways which allow IPv6 connectivity for outbound initiated connections only.

#### Virtual Private Gateway (VGW)

This can be seen as a router of sorts. If you have a VPN connecting to AWS' VPN service or if you're using Private Direct Connect, it will traverse this virtual device, which will be associated with a VPC. What's noteworthy, is that is a peering of sorts and uses VPC private IP addresses for communication. You don't need a public IP address to talk through a VGW, and you *cannot* traverse a VGW by using the public IP address of instances in your VPC.

#### VPC Peering Connections (PCX)

This is very similar to a VGW. It can only connect two VPCs (with transit gateway, I suppose this is an oversimplification), and it connects them on the Private IP address layer. You *cannot* reference resources across a PCX by using their Public IP addresses.

#### VPC Endpoint (VPC-E)

This is only accessible from inside of the VPC with connections going out (obviously return traffic with come back through this, but . It is a connection to a specific AWS Endpoint within the AWS Public Boundary (like the S3 API endpoint). This doesn't use an instance's public IP address.

## VPC Router

All traffic exiting or entering the VPC hits this router, and it routes to/from all of the egress/ingress points at the VPC boundary and to/from each of the subnets. You can adjust this router to control which traffic goes where, and you can have different route tables for each subnet. Thus a "public" subnet is one in a VPC that has a IGW and has a default route (0.0.0.0/0) to that IGW. A private subnet has no route to an IGW. If there isn't a route to an IGW, having a public IP address on your instance is useless and wasteful.

You can also route to an ENI if you want to control traffic within your VPC and send it to an EC2 Instance (web proxying / IDS / traffic capturing / etc.), however, that ENI has to reside in a subnet with a different route table, or otherwise it's own outbound traffic will be routed back to itself. All traffic exiting/entering any subnet and all traffic exiting/entering the VPC traverses this router and is subject to the routes you configure. You cannot configure routing within your subnets, any packet destined for an address within your VPC's private IP space will be automatically routed to that particular subnet, and you cannot override this functionality with more specific routes.

## Subnet Boundary

At the subnet boundary, traffic is subject to the Network Access Control Lists (NACLs). This is a stateless, rule-based firewall. By default it is wide-open and requires no configuration to allow traffic. There is no rule to allow "existing connections" so if you start to lock down a subnet with NACLs, you'll probably need to open up all of the ephemeral ports in the direction you're expecting return traffic. Any traffic between instances within the same subnet will *not* hit the NACL. But anything that leaves or enters the subnet (whether it's going to another subnet in the same VPC, or leaving the VPC altogether) will hit the NACL and be subject to its rules. Generally leave these alone, unless you need to protect traffic at the subnet level, NACLs are a little unwieldy.

## Elastic Network Interface (ENI)

Finally traffic goes through an ENI, where it is subject to a security group. This is a stateful implicit-deny firewall for which you can only add allow rules. If the security group doesn't have a rule allowing outbound traffic from the instance, that traffic will never leave the ENI. If the security group doesn't have a rule allowing a kind of inbound traffic, that kind of inbound traffic will never be sent to the Instance (i.e. the OS will not be able to detect it).

## NAT Gateway

This is a device that can reside in a subnet. It will need a route to an IGW and it will need a public IP address (Elastic IPs work). It performs a many-to-one NAT of any private IP addresses within your VPC to a publicly-routable IP (technically it performs a many-to-one NAT translating the many private IP addresses within your VPC to its one own private IP address, and when it communicates with the IGW, that does a one-to-one NAT to translate the NAT Gateway's private IP address into a public IP address). This only works for IPv4. And it only works if instances send their traffic to the NAT Gateway's ENI. Generally, you'd have a NAT Gateway reside in a public Subnet (with a default route to the IGW), and all of your instances in private subnets would have a default route to the NAT Gateway's ENI.

## Summary

Bare minimum to connect to an EC2 Instance:

- VPC has an IGW attached
- NACL has allow rules for the desired traffic in both directions (configured by default)
- EC2 Instance has a security group allowing the desired traffic (TCP/22 for SSH, etc.)
- EC2 Instance has a public IP address associated with it (must be configured when you launch the instance, or can be added afterward by attaching an Elastic IP).

This configuration allows you to directly connect to the instance over the public internet.

## Well-Architected VPC Pattern

The generic architectural pattern advised by AWS for simple best-practice networks is:

- VPC with an IGW attached
- two-or-more public subnets (each in separate availability zones) with a default route to the IGW.
- a NAT Gateway in each of the public subnets
- two-or-more private subnets (each in the same AZ as the public subnets) each with default routes to the NAT Gateway in the public subnet in the same AZ.
- a bastion host in an auto-scaling group of 1 spanning all of the public subnets allowing SSH inbound (Whether this is advisable is debatable)
- if needed, a VPN connection from your corporate network to the VPC
- security groups on the private instances allowing inbound from specific resources within the VPC (referencing by security group ID where possible) and whatever inbound traffic is needed through the VPC, and outbound traffic TCP/443 outbound to the world (or more/less depending on your risk tolerance and needs).
- if needed, and VPC Endpoint to S3 or whatever API endpoints you expect to send large volumes of traffic.

This architecture allows your private instances to connect to public internet resources outbound (using IPv4, at least), and inbound traffic has to go through the VPN or the bastion host. For public-facing services, setting up an Elastic Load Balancer in the public subnets is the desired way to provide public connectivity for your instances, so that you can continue to keep them protected in a private subnet.